# Tangential polygons: Conditions on edge lengths?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, polygons

Given any $L = (\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_n)$ edge lengths, it is possible to
construct a cyclic (inscribed) convex polygon. This can be seen by viewing the
edges are rigid bars and the vertices as universal joints. Then place a polygonal
chain with those lengths in a large-radius circle, and shrink the radius until the
chain closes to a polygon:

[image: Cyclic]

However, the same proof idea does not work for tangential polygons.
A [tangential polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_polygon) (circumscribed)
has each edge tangent to a circle:

[image]

(Image by [Claudio Rocchini in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumgon).)

My question is:

> ***Q***. Which length sequences $L = (\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots,\ell_n)$ can be realized
> as the edge lengths of a tangential polygon of $n$ vertices?
> In other words, characterize the realizable $L$.

For tangential quadrilaterals, $\ell_1+\ell_3 = \ell_2+\ell_4$, and
this generalizes for all even $n$.
But I am not sure that this necessary condition is also sufficient.
[It is for $n=4$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_quadrilateral#Characterizations), but what is known for even $n$ greater than $4$?
Nor do I know of conditions for odd $n$.

Comment: It is not sufficient for larger even $n$. For example, the edge lengths $(1,1,100,1,1,100)$ cannot form a tangential hexagon for fairly obvious reasons. I don't know what extra conditions would be sufficient.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangential_polygon#Characterizations not helpful?

Comment: @user3733558: I actually linked to that. I was hoping for something beyond the little that's mentioned there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is discussed in Djukić, Janković, Matić, Petrović, *The IMO Compendium*, pg 561, extracted below.

If the edge lengths satisfy a certain necessary and sufficient condition (basically a sanity check), then (much as for the cyclic polygons described in the question) the corresponding polygon can be found by wrapping the sequence of edges tangentially along an arc of a large circle and then shrinking the circle until the first and last edges meet up.

[image]

Comment: Great find---Thanks! Might not be easy to solve (1), but very nice that it allows a circle-shrinking argument to go through.

Comment: You're welcome!  (1) takes us into linear algebra, defining an $n\times n$ matrix.  Invertible for $n$ odd, and the inverse has an easy formula. If you have an admissable length sequence (i.e. there is a solution in positive reals), small perturbations will also be admissable. For even $n$ the matrix is not invertible, and admissable sequences are linear combinations of admissable sequences (but not necessarily the other way around) so you can't perturb them arbitrarily but you can perturb the combinations. At least that's what I see when I play with this in Mathematica.